# Typescript how can I make next/prev pages?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm making an app and I want to add pages bar similar to the one on searching websites
"(prev 1,2,3,4... next)" , I'm using Typescript and so far I managed to make content limit which called `PAGE_SIZE` and pages, the problem is I don't know how to refer this to my app.

This is server's index:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import { tempData } from './temp-data';
import { serverAPIPort, APIPath } from '@fed-exam/config';

console.log('starting server', { serverAPIPort, APIPath });

const app = express();
const PAGE_SIZE = 20;
// const PAGE_AMOUNT = tempData % PAGE_SIZE;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((_, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  next();
});

app.get(APIPath, (req, res) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const page: number = req.query.page || 1;
  const paginatedData = tempData.slice((page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE, page * PAGE_SIZE);
  res.send(paginatedData);
});

app.listen(serverAPIPort);
console.log('server running', serverAPIPort);
```

And this is my HTML elements

```
<div className='pages-bar'>
    <a href='' id='prev' className='pages-bar'>Prev</a>
    <a href=''id='next' className='pages-bar'>Next</a>
</div>
```

Should I use `href` by create a query string?

Comment: Effective pagination is a pretty deep topic. What happens if tempData changes? Now your slices might overlap, or have gaps where some users miss seeing some data. Also, modern UX usually would suggest e.g. an infinite scroll with lazy loading rather than the dated page links. Also also, at some point you're going to need to replace in-memory data with a database with it's own ideas about pagination (and now you have to deal with latency and transactional semantics and asynchrony), and then all bets are off again. This question opens a can of worms, can you narrow it down?

Comment: Lets say I'm having millions of posts it would be horrible to load it, I'm still willing to do that, should I send whole tempData and slice it inside the app?

Comment: Again, if you have millions of posts, they won't be sitting in an in-memory data structure they'll be in a database. So we can't talk about how you do this without databases (LIMIT OFFSET is probably the simplest approach although since node is a stateful webserver cursors might be a better option). Also, where in my comment did I suggest that you load the whole thing at once? My point is just that you seem to be asking for a simple answer but you are leaving out the kinds of detail that would let us give you one.